# Python MySQL inconsistent commits

Tags: python, mysql

I suspect this is mostly a mysql question.

I recently inherited some python code (I am not exactly a pythonista).  It seems like extremely trivial code that builds two queries and then sends them one at a time to the database

```
query_1 = "insert into %s SELECT Foo, Bar FROM %s where Type in ('AB','BC') group by Foo;" %(filteredTable, rawTable)
self.connect(self.credentials, query_1)

query_2 = 'insert into %s SELECT a.*, b.Bar  FROM %s a left join %s b on a.Foo  = b.Foo  ;' % (finaltable, filteredTable, otherTable)
self.connect(self.credentials, query_2)

def connect(self, credentials, query):
    connection = None
    server, user, password, database = credentials
    try:
        connection = MySQLdb.connect(server, user, password, database, connect_timeout=10)
        cursor = connection.cursor()
        cursor.execute(query)
        result = cursor.fetchall()
    except MySQLdb.Error, e:
        self.logger.exception('event_description="Error with mysql"')
        raise
    if connection:
        connection.close()
    return result
```

query_2 works, query_1 fails unless I add a cursor.execute("COMMIT;").

I can fix this easily enough in my code, but I'm dumbfounded at why this would be.  Why does one succeed without a commit while the other fails?

Comment: Just as a rule of thumb, regardless of the DBMS you are using, it is best to manually execute commits when you want them, other than depending on your API to know the right time to execute them.

Comment: Thanks willOEM.  I've started reviewing the other dynamic sql statements in the code base for similar issues.